# Django CreateView not updating context data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I have a form in a bootstrap modal, and I want to keep that modal open after submission. I am using CreateView and trying to pass an additional variable to the template in front-end where I could check if the flag is set or not, but the flag is always False even after submission. Here is what I have:

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MescData

urlpatterns = [
    path('mesc', MescData.as_view(), name='mesc')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from .forms import MescForm
from .models import Mesc


class MescData(CreateView):
    model = Mesc
    form_class = MescForm
    template_name = 'Materials/mesc_data.html'
    successful_submit = False  # Flag to keep the add entry modal open

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['successful_submit'] = self.successful_submit
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('mesc')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        self.successful_submit = True

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        # self.successful_submit = True
        return super(MescData, self).form_valid(form, **kwargs)
```

And in Template, I'm checking it like this:

```
{% if successful_submit %}
    <h1>Flag is set</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to pass non-form-related data in CreateView to the template without having to change the url.py (i.e. adding variable data to url path)?

EDIT:

I tried printing the self.successful_submit in form_valid() and post() methods and it is indeed being updated to True, but in the template it is still being passed on as False.

Comment: Sorry I made that mistake while typing it down here. It has been `successful_submit` all along. I have updated the code here.

Comment: You're setting `form.successful_submit` instead of `self.successful_submit` in the `post` method. Saying that, you could just check for `request.POST` in your template.

Comment: @Bobort Thank you for clarifying this. I changed that value but still got the same issue. The value is indeed getting changed when I check it in the form_valid() and post() method, but it is not working in the front-end and stays False.

Comment: I would forget about setting the flag and just do a condition testing `request.POST`.  `{% if request.POST %}<h1>Post Successful</h1>{% endif %}`  Saying that, your `success_url` is probably not pointing back to the `CreateView`. By default, I think it points to the `get_absolute_url` of the instance. So you're not going to see that variable set anyway after a successful submission.

Comment: I have updated the post with my urls.py. Could you please check if that is the case?

Comment: Your success_url just redirects to the CreateView (I assume) which is a request.GET and a completely fresh call of the CreateView.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I think you're going about it all wrong. You need to do ajax to update the contents of a modal after you've posted it.

Comment: Doesn't it work like get() method from TemplateView (or View) where the get() method is fetched before the page is rendered; whether it is the initial render or after post()?

Comment: After you do a post, Django returns the response provided by `get_success_url`. I suppose if you really want to re-render the same template, you could just override `get_success_url` with the corresponding render statement. But it's a very non-standard way of doing it and could cause more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Alright. As much as I hate it, I guess I'll go with passing flags through url parameters. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax?

Comment: Javascript is one language I am terrible at, and I do not enjoy using it at all. So naturally I have never been good with using ajax calls even though they are very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the core problem: "I have a form in a bootstrap modal, and I want to keep that modal open after submission."

Simple answer: Use Ajax.

We do now have HTML over the wire as a paradigm gaining popularity, but I'm not familiar enough with it to discuss it. So I will use Ajax to show a solution. This particular solution uses a general ajax template, and the result of a post is a rendered Django template that you can use to just replace the HTML in your already rendered page.

Also, few people like JavaScript, but that is not a good enough reason to avoid using it. It is basically mandatory in any web application you're running. Even HTML over the wire uses a minimal amount of JavaScript to accomplish its goals.

First, write your Ajax view. I'm using django-rest-framework classes for this, and I'm providing an example for filling out a Calibration record. You can use whatever form you want; this is just my recipe for handling modals that you want keep open. In this view, I return a JSON response if the POST was successful. Otherwise, I return a rendered Django template.

```
from rest_framework.generics import (CreateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView,
                                     UpdateAPIView, get_object_or_404)
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CalibrationCreateAjaxView(CreateAPIView, UpdateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
    template_name = "documents/form/cal.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context(request)
        calibration_form = context['calibration_form']
        if calibration_form.is_valid():
            calibration_form.save()
            request.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
            return Response(status=201)
        return Response(context, status=400)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(self.get_context(request))

    @staticmethod
    def get_context(request):
        pk = request.GET.get("pk")
        calibration_entry = get_object_or_404(CalibrationEntry, pk=pk) if pk else None
        return {
            'calibration_form': CalibrationFormAjax(request.POST or None, instance=calibration_entry)
        }
```

I have my view template as well. It takes advantage of request.is_ajax, which is being deprecated. You'll need to add some middleware to keep using it. Here's my middleware. Add it to your settings file as well.

```
class IsAjaxMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    """
    request.is_ajax is being removed in Django 4
    Since we depend on this in our templates, we are adding this attribute to request
    Please review:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.1/#id2
    """
    def __call__(self, request):
        request.is_ajax = request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
        return self.get_response(request)
```

general/ajax_modal.html

```
<!-- {% block modal_id %}{% endblock %}{% block modal_title %}{% endblock %} -->
{% block modal_body %}
{% endblock modal_body %}
```

general/modal.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{% block modal_id %}{{ modal_id }}{% endblock modal_id %}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    {% block modal_title %}{{ modal_title }}{% endblock modal_title %}
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% block modal_body %}
                {% endblock modal_body %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even though, we're using Crispy Forms, you can get away without using it. I also have a general templatetag library that renders any errors on a form. You can write your own.

documents/form/cal.html

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:'general\ajax_modal.html,general\modal.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags general %}
{% block modal_id %}new-cal-modal{% endblock modal_id %}
{% block modal_title %}Enter Calibration Information{% endblock modal_title %}
{% block modal_body %}
<div id="new-cal-form-container">
    <form action="{% url 'calibration-create' %}" method="post" id="new-cal-modal-form" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
        {% if request.is_ajax %}
            {% crispy calibration_form %}
            {% form_errors calibration_form %}
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success button" id="submit">save</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock modal_body %}
```

So now that the Ajax view is all set up, I go back to the main page that will render the modal dialog when the user clicks a button. I have a block called "extraContent" in which I include the template of the modal form.

```
{% block extraContent %}
    {% include 'documents/form/cal.html' %}
{% endblock extraContent %}
```

And now, the JavaScript, which requires jQuery, that I've added to the template. I guess I made my own jQuery plugin on top of that...

```
$.fn.modalFormContainer = function(optionsObject) {
    //call it on the modal div (the div that contains a modal-dialog, which contains modal-header, modal-body, etc
    //  we expect there to be a form within that div, and that form should have an action url
    //  when buttons that trigger the modal are clicked, the form is fetched from that action url and replaced.
    // optionsObject has formAfterLoadFunction and ajaxDoneFunction
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.modalFormContainer.defaults, optionsObject);
    var $modalFormContainer = $(this);
    // get the buttons that trigger this modal to open
    //  add a click event so that the form is fetched whenever the buttons are clicked
    //  if data-pk is an attribute on the button, apply that to the querystring of the
    //      ajaxURL when fetching the form
    var modalID = $modalFormContainer.prop("id");
    var modalFormButtonSelector = "[data-target=#" + modalID + "][data-toggle=modal]";

    function handleModalButtonClick(event) {
        //does the button have an associated pk? if so add the pk to the querystring of the ajax url
        //   this is wrapped in a form so that it gets replaced by the ajax response.
        var $button = $(this);
        if (!$button.hasClass("disabled") && !$button.prop("disabled")) { //only do it if the button is "enabled"
            var $placeholder = $("<form><h1>loading...</h1></form>");
            var $modalForm = $modalFormContainer.find("form");
            var ajaxURL = $modalForm.prop("action");
            $modalForm.replaceWith($placeholder);
            var pk = $button.data().pk;
            if (pk) {
                if (ajaxURL.indexOf("?") > 0) {
                    ajaxURL += "&pk=" + pk;
                } else {
                    ajaxURL += "?pk=" + pk;
                }
            }
            //fetch the form and replace $modalFormContainer's contents with it
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: ajaxURL
            }).done(function(response) {
                // re-create the form from the response
                $modalFormContainer.find(".modal-body").html(response);
                $modalForm = $modalFormContainer.find("form"); //we would still need to find the form
                options.formAfterLoadFunction($modalForm);
            });
        } else {
            return false; //don't trigger the modal.
        }

    }
    //using delegation here so that dynamically added buttons will still have the behavior.
    // maybe use something more specific than '.main-panel' to help with performance?
    $(".main-panel").on("click", modalFormButtonSelector, handleModalButtonClick);

    $modalFormContainer.on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form
        event.preventDefault();
        var $modalForm = $(event.target);
        var ajaxURL = $modalForm.prop("action");
        $modalForm.find("[type=submit]").addClass("disabled").prop("disabled", true);
        var formData = $modalForm.serialize();
        var internal_options = {
            url: ajaxURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData
        };
        // file upload forms have and enctype attribute
        //    we should not process files to be converted into strings
        if ($modalForm.attr("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
            internal_options.processData = false;
            internal_options.contentType = false;
            internal_options.cache = false;
            formData = new FormData($modalForm.get(0));
            internal_options.data = formData;
        }
        $.ajax(internal_options).done(function(response) {
            // blank out the form
            $modalForm.find("input:visible, select:visible, textarea:visible").val("");
            // remove errors on the form
            $modalForm.find(".has-error").removeClass("has-error");
            $modalForm.find("[id^=error]").remove();
            $modalForm.find(".alert.alert-block.alert-danger").remove();
            // hide the modal
            $(".modal-header .close").click();
            options.ajaxDoneFunction(response);
        }).fail(function(data) {
            // re-create the form from the response
            $modalFormContainer.find(".modal-body").html(data.responseText);
            options.formAfterLoadFunction($modalForm);
        });
    });

    return this;
};

$.fn.modalFormContainer.defaults = {
    formAfterLoadFunction: function($form) { return; },
    ajaxDoneFunction: function(response) { return; }
};

$("#new-cal-modal").modalFormContainer({
    formAfterLoadFunction: function($modalForm) {
        $(".datetimeinput").datepicker('destroy');
        $(".datetimeinput").datepicker();
    },
    ajaxDoneFunction: function(event) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

So upon reviewing this, I've realized that this recipe is far more complicated than I have tricked myself into believing. I sincerely apologize for that. I hope that you can review the code and get an idea of what is happening. There are some edge cases, such as dealing with dates and file uploads, that this recipe handles right now, but you may not actually need them. I should mention that the application that this came from is using Bootstrap 3, so its styling is not updated to the current Bootstrap 5 as of this writing. I should add that the main content of the app has a class of "main-panel" as used in this not-so-generic jQuery plugin.

I'm worried that I've gone and overwhelmed you into maintaining your position of trying to keep using a standard POST request. I guess you could just re-render the template with your POST since it'll be standard practice in your project. You could still get away without using a query string that way.

Comment: This is a great approach for people who are using DRF. My use case is simple, so DRF is a bit of an overkill for me (at least at this point in the project). Plus that would force me to rewrite everything that I've done so far, such as the django-tables2 library I'm using which I have discovered does not play well with classes that have the shares the same MRO. And the unofficial bootstrap5 template of crispy-forms which would not work as well in the same page if I'm serializing the objects. 

I have accepted your answer as it might help someone else that has the same use case.